# controller gets request parameter null in http post mthod

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Im testing my post via Postman and I get data,when I post the following url(i add the ip hardcoded):

```
http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/?id=192.168.10.801
```

but in angular side when I try the same thing,i get id=null in .netcore

```
url: http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/
 this.http.post(this.url,{params:{id:x} });
```

**my controller:**

```
       public IActionResult turbineDvic(string id)
        {


            var x = _acess.Devices(id);



            return Ok(x);

        }
```

**I tried :**

```
([FromBody]string id)
```

but that gives my error 405! which I never seen, any idea?seems i ca not add the parameter to my url

Comment: In postman you are trying query params? is it a GET call or POST call?

Comment: @SelakaN its post

Comment: So I dont see the IP address part in the url you have provided in angular app? For ex: its just this `http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/` you are missing the full url `http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/?id=192.168.130.101` Check wether if it is the problem and let me know I'll post the answer

Comment: @SelakaN in my controller i get id=null via angular thats the issue

Comment: Sre you sure it's  it an Options request reaching your controller?

Comment: @David it reaches my controller i put a break point,but i get id null!

Comment: I was suggesting that it may be the CORS OPTIONS request hiring your breakpoint. Try posting to `http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/?id=192.168.130.101` directly, without angular params. Does that work? And yet comparing headers from chrome network debugger to postman headers.

Comment: @David yes in that way workd,when i try to post http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/?id=192.168.130.101 i get the ip on the back-end1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post method for HttpClient needs a body as second parameter. Try passing an empty body

```
this.http.post(this.url, {}, { params:{id:x} }
```

Comment: wow!works and can you tell me what that body could be usually?and why we need it

Comment: The body is for the data that you usually send with http post requests. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16339198/1160794